# GitLab Helm Chart Minio use existing PVC

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, helm

Previously in my helm chart, I had the snippet below...

```yaml
minio:
  replicas: 1
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    existingClaim: minio
    #size: 10Gi
  serviceType: LoadBalancer
```

Because I do have an existing PVC that I intend to use with Minio.  It worked fine, up until a couple months ago, when GitLab changed their chart format up.

Now, it shows that I can set `minio.persistence.volumeName` to use an existing volume name, but not the existing PVC.

How can I configure Minio to use an existing PVC now using the GitLab helm chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--set minio.persistence.existingClaim=minio-pvc`  when running helm install/upgrade.